# img tag in figure tag with classes doesn't work

Tags: html, css, class, xampp, less

I'm having a weird error that I can't figure out myself.

I have an image tag inside a figure tag(tested with div tag also), but when I add classes to the figure tag, then the Image doesn't show. It does show if I don't add the classes though.

I'm using LESS with a compiler, so it compiles it to css automatically.

HTML for that part:

```
        <div class="span9 clearfix">

            <figure class="ad-block fr top-ad">
                <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/468/60" alt="Ad" /></a>
            </figure>

        </div> <!-- end span9 -->
```

CSS for these tags:

```
.ad-block {
    .box-shadow(0px, 0px, 5px, @border-color);
    img {
        display: block;
    }
}

.top-ad {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.fr { float: right; }

figure {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Images showing the error:

With tags

http://www.bildites.lv/images/2rzac0wyi01ekhhvn7b.png

Without tags

http://www.bildites.lv/images/aq3agebpc7a5o3efltc.png

I tried to use only one class to test things.  The only class that worked was fr(float:right;)
The weird thing is that even if I leave only ad-block or top-ad class and comment out all the css styling of that class, the image is still don't show up. 
I can't manage to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using localhost, xampp, if that changes something.

EDIT: It turns out that I'm super forgetful about the adblocker that I recently added to my testing browser. Disabling it fixed the problem. Thanks Mr Lister and jthe for fast comments. :)

Comment: So to recap, the image that is in a container with class `ad-block` and/or `top-ad` doesn't show up, no matter the CSS? How odd. And it does this on all browsers, or only on ones with ad blockers installed?

Comment: Yes it looks like an ad blocker is hidding the content because it has detected a block with a class name containing the 'ad' keyword. I had the same case recently with a facebook container and the ghostery chrome plugin.

Comment: Oh My God. I ussully test everything on firefox because I knew that my chrome had adblocker installed, but I forgot that I added it to firefox before few days too.
I'm so oblivious. Actually I'm surprised, that adblocker catched just a simple image as an ad.
Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I'm super forgetful about the adblocker that I recently added to my testing browser. Disabling Ad Blocker it fixed the problem. Thanks Mr Lister and jthe for fast comments. :)